# How to find the Cartesian equation of a plane in this example (in details)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm solving an A Level paper, and came across this question. Basically, they have given plane $p$ has the equation $(\mathbf r-3\mathbf i)\cdot(2\mathbf i-3\mathbf j+6\mathbf k)=0$. Now, I can see that this means dot product, but I don't understand how to find the Cartesian equation (in the form $ax+by+cz=d$). I have no clue about how to do this and so haven't tried to solve it. According to the mark scheme, the normal of the plane is $2\mathbf i-3\mathbf j+6\mathbf k$ and that is all that's given. Thanks in advance!

Edit: couldn't explain the question properly so here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the Mark Scheme:

[image]

Edit: It seems the question is missing details. However, I have provided everything I could possibly provide, along with my understanding of the question (in the comments). I really don't know what to do. If I somehow understand the question and solve it correctly, I will update this question with my answer.

Comment: What are $r,i,j,k$? Where is this plane situated? Is it a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ or in higher dimensions?

Comment: This is a basic 3D vectors question. I'm updating my question with a screenshot of the question paper.

Comment: OK so this confirms my intuition that $\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k}$ are the 3D canonical versors. But $\mathbf{r}$? It seems to be a generic point on $l$, but it seems strange that a _generic_ point from a line should enter an equation for a plane…

Comment: For bold math use `\mathbf`. $\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$ = `$\mathbf i,\mathbf j,\mathbf k$`. That said, $2\mathbf i-3\mathbf j+6\mathbf k$ can alternately be written as $(2,-3,6)$, and personally I prefer this notation since I usually use this one and not the versor one which sounds physicist-y.

Comment: @MickG, that's exactly what I was wondering. $\mathbf r$ is the only thing I haven't understood. I'm attaching the mark scheme if that helps.

Comment: This is a fine question, which I nominate for re-opening.

Comment: Meanwhile, here, briefly, is what I think is happening. It's really just a matter of notation. $i,j,k$ are as already explained in earlier comments. In your screenshot, the variable $r$ is playing different roles in the first and second sentences. Also, the equations in those two sentences have different meanings. The first sentence is expressing a line as the set of values of a dependent, vector valued variable $r$ expressed as a function of an independent real valued variable $s$. The second sentence is expressing a plane as the solution set of an equation in the vector valued variable $r$.

Comment: $\mathbf r$ is the equation of the line. The equation of the plane shows tells us that $\mathbf r $ plus a point $\mathbf -3i$ (possibly on the plane) are perpendicular (because dot product is equated to zero). What I think it could mean is that if the line is shifted $\mathbf -3i$ from its original place, it is perpendicular to the plane. This is the only question I could find of this type in 13 years worth of papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think after @Lee's comment. That $\mathbf r$ is a generic point on the line $l$ in the first equation, and a generic point of $p$ in the second one. So to intersect $l$ and $p$ you have to make the vector $\mathbf r$ have the form in the first equation and satisfy the second one:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf r=(1,6,-3)+s(1,-2,2) \\
(\mathbf r-(3,0,0))\cdot(2,-3,6)=0
\end{array}\right.$$

I suggest you write $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$. Hence, you will get the following equations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x=1+s \\
y=6-2s \\
z=-3+2s \\
(x-3)2+y(-3)+z6=0
\end{array}\right.$$

Solve for $s$, then substitute the result in $(x,y,z)=(1+s,6-2s,-3+2s)$ and that will be $A$. Let me do it:

\begin{align*}
(1+s-3)2-3(6-2s)+6(2s-3)=0\iff{}&s(2+6+12)+2-6-18-18=0\iff{} \\
{}\iff{}&s=\frac{18+18+6-2}{20}=\frac{40}{20}=2.
\end{align*}

Hence:

$$A=(1+2,6-2\cdot2,-3+2\cdot2)=(3,2,1).$$

Now to address the question of the cartesian equations, rewriting the equation yields:

$$(x-3,y,z)\cdot(2,-3,6)=0\iff 2x-3y+6z=6.$$

Geometrically, $p$ is the plane through $(3,0,0)$ perpendicular to $(2,-3,6)$, because a generic point on the plane, if moved by $-(3,0,0)$, ends up on the orthogonal complement to $(2,-3,6)$, which is what the equation given in the paper tells us. Hence, $(2,-3,6)$ is a normal vector (or at least, parallel to a normal vector) to $p$.

While we're at it, let me do the other points of the question. The acute angle, for example. One trick to do that is to compute the angle between the line and the normal vector, and then take $90$ degrees minus that angle to obtain the desired angle. Call the angle between the line and the plane $\alpha$. It will have to satisfy:

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{(2,-3,6)\cdot(1,-2,2)}{\|(2,-3,6)\|\|(1,-2,2)\|},$$

because the line $l$ is parallel to $(1,-2,2)$ and the plane is orthogonal to $(2,-3,6)$. Note that I am doing exactly the "e.g." product in the mark scheme. So:

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{2+6+12}{\sqrt{4+9+36}\sqrt{1+4+4}}=\frac{20}{\sqrt{49}\sqrt{9}}=\frac{20}{7\cdot3}=\frac{20}{21}.$$

Thus:

$$\alpha=\arccos\frac{20}{21}=.30984464\mathrm{rad}.$$

But our angle was:

$$\beta=\frac\pi2-\alpha=1.260951687\mathrm{rad}=72.24720984\text{˚}.$$

Look at the mark scheme: we got it right.

The last point is to find a line lying in $p$, orthogonal to $l$ and passing through $A$. The best way here is to find two linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $(2,-3,6)$, then find a combination of those two orthogonal to $(1,-2,2)$ and find the line through $A$ parallel to that combination. The fact it is a combination of vectors orthogonal to the normal vector to $p$ makes it a vector in $p$, when moved by $(3,0,0)$, the fact it's orthogonal to the direction of $l$ makes it orthogonal to $l$, and then we make it pass through $A$. One easy vector orthogonal to $(2,-3,6)$ is $(0,2,1)$. Another easy one is $(3,2,0)$. These are evidently independent. So let us try finding $a(0,2,1)+b(3,2,0)$ orthogonal to $(1,-2,2)$, that is:

$$(3b,2b+2a,a)\cdot(1,-2,2)=0\iff 3b-4b-4a+2a=0\iff -b-2a=0\iff b=-2a.$$

For example, with $a=1$ we get $b=-2$. So our combination will be $(3(-2),2(-2)+2\cdot1,1)=(-6,-2,1)$. So our line will be $A+s(-6,-2,1)$, or:

$$(3,2,1)+s(-6,-2,1).$$

Obviously our choice of the combination had some degree of arbitrariness. For example, if we multiply $(-6,-2,1)$ by any real number we will get the same line if we use the multiple instead of it in the line's equation. For example, multiplying by $-1$ gives us exactly the equation in the scheme's last OR.